# Matrix algebra: can I invert this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose there is a rank-$K$ matrix $\mathbf{X}$ that has dimensions $G \times K$ with $G > K$. The $K \times G$ matrix $\mathbf{L}$ is defined as:

$\mathbf{L} \equiv (\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'$

The question is: can I solve to find $\mathbf{X}$ as a function of $\mathbf{L}$? Is the solution unique? Is the following ever a solution?

$\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{L}'(\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}')^{-1}$

I'm sure there must be a simple answer to this but I don't know what to look up.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

Beware of the different sizes of the matrices. Remember that for a matrix to be invertible it needs to be square first. In this spirit, while $(X'X)$ might be invertible, $X$ alone is not.
You can try the following:
\begin{align*}
 L&= (X'X)^{-1}X' \\
 LX&= (X'X)^{-1}X'X \\
 LX&= I_{k} \\
 L'LX &=L'\\
 X&=(L'L)^{-1}L'
\end{align*}
I invite you to plug this expression for $X$ back into the first line and check for yourself it is valid.

And as a recommendation for your future questions: it is customary to include what you have tried towards solving your question to help those who answer identify where your difficulties lie and structure their answers accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this works: since $L$ is $K \times G$ and rank $K < G$, we have $L'L$ is $G \times G$ and rank $K < G$ so is not invertible. Am I mistaken?

Comment: You are correct!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked out the answer.

We start with $\mathbf{L} \equiv (\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'$. This implies $\mathbf{L}\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{I}$ as Fede notes. As a result we can write
\begin{align}
\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}' &= (\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{L}' \\
&=(\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{X})^{-1}
\end{align}
because $\mathbf{X}'\mathbf{L}' = (\mathbf{L}\mathbf{X})' = \mathbf{I}' =\mathbf{I}$. We can then substitute this into the definition for $\mathbf{L}$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{L} &\equiv \mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}'\mathbf{X}' \\
(\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}')^{-1}\mathbf{L} &= \mathbf{X}' \\
\mathbf{X} &= \mathbf{L}'(\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}')^{-1}
\end{align}
where the inversion of $\mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}'$ is possible because it is dimension $K \times K$ and rank $K$ (the latter because $X$ is rank $K$).